# Array of custom object is not being set

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, mapkit

I am trying to store an Object, `CustomPinAnnotation` into an array. I have declared it like this: `var pinArray = [CustomPinAnnotation]()`

I am calling Firebase in a function which gets a lot of locations in which I construct my CustomPin.

```
func loadStuff()
        _REF_BASE.child("Objects").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                    if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot]{
                        for snap in snapshots {
                            if let dict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                                let key = snap.key
                                let obj = objModel(lobbyKey: key, dictionary: pokeDict)
                                for location in obj.locations {
                                    let coord = location.locationCoordinate
                                    let customPin = CustomPinAnnotation()
                                    customPin.coordinate = coord.coordinate
                                    customPin.title = obj.name

                                    let time = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: location.time)
                                    let dayTimePeriodFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                                    dayTimePeriodFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd YYYY hh:mm a"
                                    let dateString = dayTimePeriodFormatter.stringFromDate(time)
                                    customPin._detailedDescription = "Seen at " + dateString
                                    customPin.subtitle = "Seen at \(dateString)"
                                    customPin._pokemonName = obj.name
                                    customPin._imageName = obj.name
                                    customPin._successRate = location.successRate
                                    customPin._upVotes = location.upVotes
                                    customPin._downVotes = location.downVotes
                                    customPin._caughtAtTime = dateString
                                    self.pinToPass = customPin // send this custom pin with info
                                    self.pinArray.append(customPin)
    // self.mapView.addAnnotation(customPin);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  }
                })
```

My ViewDidLoad method

self.PokeMapView.zoomEnabled = true

```
    loadStuff()
    self.mapView.addAnnotations(pinArray)
    self.mapView.showAnnotations(pinArray, animated: true)
```

The commented line `//self.MapView.addAnnotation(customPin)` currently works, but this is very inefficient, as it would pin objects on the map that are not in the current scope of the map itself. However, when I try adding the list of Annotations like so: `MapView.addAnnotations(pinArray)`, nothing works and via the debugger i'm told that the array contains 0 elements.

It'd be greatly appreciated if somebody could help me, as i've been stuck on this for a while and it really causes poor performance.

Comment: if you log `self.pinArray` right after the append, what do you see?

Comment: `<Project.CustomPinAnnotation: 0x14b28fed0>` <- Thousands of these

Comment: It was printing for over 2 minutes, so maybe since it's inside of an async call, the map is displayed before it's done adding all the array?

Comment: Would need to see more code.

Comment: Updated with all the code I talked about